# Trying to use results from one query to combine with results from new query in parse.com - javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Let's consider the following data:
Data table 1:

```
item1   item2
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        4
```

Data table 2:

```
item1    nameItem1
1        fred
2        sam
```

I'm trying to write a javascript query that would first retrieve data from `table1` based on `item2`.
Then, it would use the item1 from that result, and search table2 for the name.
And for output, I'd get the following:

```
item2     nameItem1
1         fred
1         sam
```

I'm using parse.com as my database, and am failing miserably at this.  Here is a sample of my javascript code:

```
var className = "seminarAttendance";   //change this to the appropriate class name

var query = new Parse.Query(className);

query.equalTo("StudentID", attendancesearch.studentID.value);

query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        if(results.length==0){

        alert("Sorry, there are no results that match your search.")
            {return;}}

        var w = window.open();
        w.document.write('<html><head><title>Result Table</title>');
        w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" >');
        w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablesearch.css" type="text/css" />');           
        w.document.write(' </head><body><h3> Here are your search results!</h3><br/>');
        w.document.write(' Student # ' + attendancesearch.studentID.value + ' has attended ' +results.length + ' seminars <br>');
        w.document.write('<div class="search"><table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" >');
        w.document.write('<thead><tr><td><b>Seminar ID</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td><td><b>Time Period</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td></tr></thead><tbody>');

        for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
            var object = results[i];

            var semid = object.get("SeminarID");
            var studid=object.get("StudentID");
            var timeper=object.get("timePeriodID");

            var semclass = "seminarTable";
            var query2 = Parse.Query(semclass);
            query2.equalTo("seminarID", semid);
            query2.first({

            success:  function(q2object){

            var test = q2object.get("seminarName");
            },
            });

            w.document.write('<tr>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + semid + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + studid + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + timeper + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + test + '</td>');
            w.document.write('</tr>');
        }
        w.document.write('</tbody></table></div></body></html>');
        w.document.close();
```

Comment: You have forgotten "new" in var query2 = Parse.Query(semclass);. It should be var query2 = new Parse.Query(semclass);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call query2 in a 'for' loop.Because querying takes some time which is much larger than execution of 'for' loop.
Instead you can fetch all the objects of "seminarTable" class and store them in another array (say results1).
Now we have results and results1 arrays,so you can search manually and put conditions.

```
var className = "seminarAttendance";   //change this to the appropriate class name

var query = new Parse.Query(className);

query.equalTo("StudentID", attendancesearch.studentID.value);

query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    if(results.length==0){

    alert("Sorry, there are no results that match your search.")
        {return;}}

    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write('<html><head><title>Result Table</title>');
    w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" >');
    w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablesearch.css" type="text/css" />');           
    w.document.write(' </head><body><h3> Here are your search results!</h3><br/>');
    w.document.write(' Student # ' + attendancesearch.studentID.value + ' has attended ' +results.length + ' seminars <br>');
    w.document.write('<div class="search"><table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" >');
    w.document.write('<thead><tr><td><b>Seminar ID</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td><td><b>Time Period</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td><td><b>Student ID</b></td></tr></thead><tbody>');




    var semclass = "seminarTable";
    var query2 = Parse.Query(semclass);
    query2.find({
        success:  function(results1){
           //Do whatever you want here
            w.document.write('<tr>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + semid + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + studid + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + timeper + '</td>');
            w.document.write('<td>' + test + '</td>');
            w.document.write('</tr>');
        },
        });


    }
    w.document.write('</tbody></table></div></body></html>');
    w.document.close();
```